# Password issue when using shares

Tags: login, password

I have Ubuntu 21.10 gnome Desktop installed. When I first installed it I used a very easy login password.

Later I decided I would change it and make it more secure. I changed my password and logged in.

Everything is working like it is supposed to but the weird thing is today I decided to access a shared folder from another computer when trying to access the share it kept saying my login credentials were wrong so for kicks I tried my old password that was very simple and it let me right in. I cant figure out why this is.

There is only one account on the Ubuntu desktop.
The password (New) is also the root password but doing a sudo command still asks for it but that seems like it should be that way.

I just dont understand why that share would want the old password that is no longer used on the machine.

Also when I go to users under settings in Ubuntu I see just the one account the password is all asteriks but looks short like my old password so I thought maybe I need to change it there as well for some reason. but it wont let me change it when I type in the old easy password and change it to the new password that I already use to login.

I am really confused now. Im not a complete noob to Linux but I am no way a pro either and this has me confused. At least I can login and access everything just fine. but I have to remember to use the old password accessing the share from another computer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 21.10
Release: 21.10
Codename: impish It is the desktop version Gnome. Everytime I try to hit enter on my keyboard to start a new paragraph now it just posts my comment and I have to go back and edit it. lol

Comment: Even if I put my comment with paragraphs in a different text editor with paragraphs and paste it here it posts it as one long paragraph so I dont know what else to do about that sorry.

Comment: Is this a samba share? If so it's possible you set a password for the share using smbpasswd and used the same simple password there. If this is the case we can write an answer around changing that.

Comment: I believe it is. All I did to create the share was right click the folder and clicked "Local Network Share" I then shared it without and tried with adding guest access before trying the old password from the other computer which let me in.    I am not very good with terminal commands but sure am good at copying them and pasting them from you pro's

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the users samba password needs to be updated.

Try this as root:
`smbpasswd  -U <your username>`

It will prompt for a new password.

For example:
`smbpasswd  -U Garfield`

Or just `smbpasswd` as the user you want to change.